# Passing cookie through python websocket client

Tags: python, node.js, cookies, websocket, python-requests

I am using the [websocket-client](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client) to connect to a node.js server (which is my websocket server), and I have been able to send messages through websockets from python to node.js successfully.

My python client uses the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module to login to a website and collect the cookies (that are passed from the server as a result of successful login). I would like these cookies to be passed as a part of websocket-client as shown in the code [here](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client/blob/1b37c10c1c1c655bced557fb3b762f3ace8f3e1a/websocket/_core.py#L248).

I get the following cookies from login:

```
(Pdb) requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(client.cookies)
{'csrftoken': 'DhSf0z9Ouu5f1SbfGWBg5BuBe1UuJMLr', 'sessionid': 'pu6ig4z4mtq5k8rvm6kuv8g3fdegs47d'}
```

How do I send that cookie when I create the websocket?

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8080/",
                          on_message = on_message,
                          on_error = on_error,
                          on_close = on_close,
                          # cookie = ? what goes here ?
    )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is simply this:

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8080/",
                          on_message = on_message,
                          on_error = on_error,
                          on_close = on_close,
                          cookie = "csrftoken=DhSf0z9Ouu5f1SbfGWBg5BuBe1UuJMLr; sessionid=pu6ig4z4mtq5k8rvm6kuv8g3fdegs47d"
)
```

It is meant to pass a simple string

Comment: Try `cookie = "csrftoken=DhSf0z9Ouu5f1SbfGWBg5BuBe1UuJMLr; sessionid=pu6ig4z4mtq5k8rvm6kuv8g3fdegs47d"`

Comment: It doesn't work with the syntax of the accepted answer above for me with websocket-client 0.53, but it is working using the syntax of comment by @libertylocked.